# Auth0 Callback URL mismatch for new allowed callback URL

Tags: auth0

I have an Auth0 application with a few localhost URLs as allowed callback URLs. Example: `https://127.0.0.1:8080/login, https://127.0.0.1:8080/results, https://127.0.0.1:8080/user`

When I start the authentication flow using one of the previous allowed URLs, everything works as expected.
Example:
https://tenant.auth0.com/authorize?audience=my-api&response_type=token&client_id=client-id&redirect_uri=https://127.0.0.1:8080/results

I want to support a new allowed URL: `https://mynicedomain.com`
So I added it to the allowed list; however, it doesn't work when I go to: https://tenant.auth0.com/authorize?audience=my-api&response_type=token&client_id=client-id&redirect_uri=https://mynicedomain.com

I tried adding `/` in both, Auth0 conf and in the URL. Also, add it as allowed URL origins but I can't still make it work.

Did anyone have a similar issue? I read several posts and Auth0 docs and I cannot find what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Have you tried using a path, as in `redirect_uri=https://mynicedomain.com/auth`? Otherwise, what "doesn't work" — what happens and when?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain this is an exact match for the OP's issue, but given that the symptoms are the same, in my scenario the actual issue was caused by a proxy in front of the application using `http` and not `https` to speak to the application at the host where the deployed application lives (eg. production).

The issue is described at this forum link in more detail:
https://community.auth0.com/t/asp-net-core-loginexternal-not-working-with-https/7824

The way to fix it for applications registered as **Regular Web Application** at Auth0 is to intercept the redirect to identity provider and forcefully rewrite the scheme to be `https`.

Implementing this change in code will resemble the following (in Program.cs in C# for Blazor, or whereever one's setup code resides):

```
options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
{
    OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) => {
        var builder = new UriBuilder(context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri);

        builder.Scheme = "https";

        context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = builder.ToString();

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    },

    // ... more handlers here, etc.
};
```

Note that if the builder is still trying to redirect to the normal `http` port (80) even after forcing protocol scheme, then more aggressive URI rewriting may be needed.

Example:

1. Callback URL at Auth0: https://my-app-hostname/
2. Builder is forced to https, but somehow the internals force http instead by port: https://my-app-hostname:80/
3. Registering that url with explicit port 80 works at Auth0, but then on callback it fails at the proxy because https://my-app-hostname:80/ is not valid (listener on port 80 is not `https`).